# Problem integrating GWT and OSGi

Tags: gwt, osgi, equinox

I have a problem integrating GWT into OSGi Equinox container. The entry point webpage runs. I see my first page. However, when I click on a button to realize server call, it does not run.
I work with Firefox and I have firebug. Then, when I see network field I get the next message:

```
Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Cache-Control   must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length  1431
Server  Jetty(6.1.x)

Host    localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8
X-GWT-Permutation   CCF6A1341D371C4123AE827BC29EA602
X-GWT-Module-Base   http://localhost/zbapp/zb_app/
Referer http://localhost/zbapp/ZB_app.html
Content-Length  174
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

Post method:

```
7|0|6|http://localhost/zbapp/zb_app/|A31E1254E17F9AD731856D6BE34124A2|main.java.com.gwt.app.client.GreetingService|greetServer|java.lang.String/2004016611||1|2|3|4|2|5|5|6|6|
```

And response:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 ProxyServlet: /zbapp/zb_app/greet</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /zbapp/zb_app/greet. Reason:
<pre>    ProxyServlet: /zbapp/zb_app/greet</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by     Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                                                         
</body>
</html>


Problem accessing /zbapp/zb_app/greet. Reason:
ProxyServlet: /zbapp/zb_app/greet
```

It looks the call is performed, but it can not access. I do not know the problem. Could someone help me? I need to solve it to integrate it with other services.

Thanks a lot!

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to work with Spring, but I have integrated an OSGi bundle with GWT, and hopefully this will help you do that.

Have a look at this: http://bryanhunt.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/osgi-as-a-web-application-server/. The tutorial shows how to integrate a servlet into an OSGi bundle, step by step. Then have a look at this http://wiki.eclipse.org/Google_Web_Toolkit_and_Equinox. That link pretty much explains everything you need to know to integrate GWT into an OSGi bundle, besides how to wrap the GWT jars, which is easy to do:

In eclipse, go file > new project > plug in development > plug-in from existing jar archive. Then choose add external and pick your GWT-user jar (and GWT-dev if you want, but this isn't necessary for the server-side only stuff). You can choose to extract the jars or not, it doesn't matter. The manifest file will automatically be generated and will export all the GWT functionality. You should then simply require this bundle in your servlet bundle's manifest file.

The second minor issue with the (last) tutorial is that he states you need to remove the lines in the GWT bundle's manifest (the one you just made from the jar) that export javax.servlet.* This is correct, but when you do this you should also add the line `Require-Bundle: javax.servlet` to the GWT bundle's manifest, otherwise you will get a classloader exception.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solve the first problem, I achieved!!! I have added the extension flag on file plugin.xml as:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets">
    <servlet alias="/zbapp/zb_app/greet" class="main.java.com.gwt.app.server.GreetingServiceImpl" />
</extension>
```

However, my error changes to 500. The cause is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor
```

But I have deployed org.springframework.asm bundle and also I have added in the Import-Packages tag org.springframework.asm package.

The version of spring is 3.1.0, I do not why does it happen? I only think if the error is due to version of Spring.

Thanks!